# apache tomcat ask username and password

Tags: java, apache, netbeans-7

I have NetBeans installed using Apache Tomcat 7. I try to run a program and am prompted with the Tomcat Manager Application and asked for a username and password.

First off I am unable to change the password under the properties of the Apache Tomcat server. I can change the username but no matter what the password always stays the same. I edited the tomcat-user.xml file both in the Catalina home & base but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I still cannot run anything from with NetBeans. I get Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager. 
See the server log for details.

it showing following error while starting the server

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\logs\catalina.2014-02-22.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:389)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:479)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\logs\localhost.2014-02-22.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:389)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:479)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\logs\manager.2014-02-22.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:389)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:479)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\logs\host-manager.2014-02-22.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:389)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:479)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
```

Comment: Is netbeans using a different tomcat-users.xml than you are editing?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Vista or newer, need Administrative rights to write something under the `C:\Program Files\` directory.
But Apache does't have administrative rights in security reasons.

That is the reason of that error.

## Edited

sorry, the answer I post explain about Apache not tomcat.

You need change log settings in tomcat configuration files like `\conf\logging.properties`, `server.xml`.

In logging.properties, you can find some `${catalina.base}/logs` values.
Change that to absolute path you like (ex `c:/path/you/like/logs`).

In server.xml, change directory attribute in Valve tag like following

```
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="c:/path/you/like/logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

or, you can also re-install tomcat another non system directory.

---

### How to modify conf file.

additional answer for following comment.

> IT SHOWING ACCESS DENIED WHEN M TRYING SAVE

To save file under some system folders include `Program Files`, you need Administrative rights.

I explain two ways to solve this problem.
You can choose either one you like.

1. Run your text editor with administrative rights.
   May be, right click short cut for editor and select `Run as administrator` or similar.
2. Edit in other place and store.
   First, copy config file you want to modify  to other place for example Desktop.
   Second, edit copied file and save.
   Third, copy (or move) to original place (the place copied from in first step ).
   after thrid step, system ask you allow or not, select allow if you want.

Sorry for my poor English.

---

following about Apache web server.

I think to solve them, you need change logs settings in configuration file.
Probably, you can find following (individual) lines in your httpd.conf

`ErrorLog "logs/error.log"`

`#CustomLog "logs/access.log" common`

`CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined`

Change these settings absolute path and uncomment about `common` like following.

`ErrorLog "c:/path/you/like/logs/error.log"`

`CustomLog "c:/path/you/like/logs/access.log" common`

`CustomLog "c:/path/you/like/logs/access.log" combined`

or you can re-install Apache another non system directory.

Comment: M SORRY BT I DNT KNOW PHYSICAL PATH WHICH I SHOULD WRITE IN  c:/path/you/like/logs??

Comment: THERE ARE 4 THREE LINES OF SET IN WHICH THAT STRING LIES IN..!!! IN WHICH 1 I HAVE TO CHANGE???

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake not physical path, absolute path is right. substitute  existing path for c:/path/you/like/logs.

Comment: yes, you find 4 `${catalina.base}/logs` ( statswith `1catalina~`, `2localhost~`, `3manager.~` and `4host~`) ,
 and you need change all of them.

Comment: IT SHOWING ACCESS DENIED WHEN M TRYING SAVE

Comment: @user3141538 I append how to modify file to my answer.

Comment: @user3141538: Can you stop yelling? I was going to assume you simply had your caps lock stuck, but you seem to legitimately be yelling at this poor answerer who's trying their best to help you (as well as the other user who left a comment on your question). Simmer down.

Comment: @fliedonion thnx for help... bt it did not work ..thn i have restore my pc... thnk a lot....

Answer (score 0):

You may configured more than one Tomcat versions in NetBeans.

or

You may installed more than one different versions of NetBeans.

Comment: yes.... u r ri8... now what to do..?? i have uninstalled older version..but problem is still there...

Comment: nice @user3141538 ...now you have to remove unnecessary tomcat from your netbeans.